# RabbitMQ store messages in exchange

Tags: php, rabbitmq, php-amqplib

I'm trying to figure out whether is possible to store messages in a RabbitMQ  exchange even when there's no consumer running.

I understood (probably incorrectly) that to achieve that the exchange needs to be "durable" as well as the queue and the message needs to be sent out with the "persistent" flag

```
'delivery_mode' => AMQPMessage::DELIVERY_MODE_PERSISTENT
```

My main goal is to store all the messages in the exchange so that, in the case that for whatever reason no consumer is running, when I launch one all the messages in the exchange can get directed to the bonded queue.
I'm declaring my exchanges and queue as follows:

```
//Sender.php
public function sendToQueue(ActionMessage $message)
    {
        $headers = [
            'content-type' => 'application/json',
            'timestamp' => $message->getCreatedAt()->getTimestamp(),
            'delivery_mode' => AMQPMessage::DELIVERY_MODE_PERSISTENT
        ];
        $channel = $this->connection->getChannel();
        $channel->exchange_declare($this->exchangeName, 'direct', false, true, false);
        $qMessage = new AMQPMessage(json_encode($message->toArray()), $headers);
        $channel->basic_publish($qMessage, $this->exchangeName, $message->getTopic());
        return true;
    }
//Receiver.php
public function consume($callbackFunction)
        {
            $channel = $this->messenger->getChannel();
            $channel->exchange_declare($this->exchange, 'direct', false, true, false);
            list($queueName, ,) = $channel->queue_declare('', false, true, true, false);
            $channel->queue_bind($queueName, $this->exchangeName, $this->topicAction);

            $channel->basic_consume($queueName, '', false, true, false, false, $callbackFunction);

            while (count($channel->callbacks)) {
                $channel->wait();
            }

            $channel->close();
            $this->messenger->close();
        }
```

I'll appreciate any help (even just to discard the idea and insert some storage in between).
Thanks.

Comment: `RabbitMQ exchange` - I think you mean `queue` an exchange is a means of delivery like `topic` or `fanout` etc..  A way of distributing messages.  If you make a queue durable, without auto delete and require ACK, You can put messages in it with no consumers.

Comment: If you have auto-delete, the queue gets deleted when there are no consumers, if you have no-ack, the messages shoot right though the queue with no waiting.  (durable might be optional but, it's not a bad idea).  That is just off the top of my head, but I am pretty sure those would cause issue if they are set wrong, for obvious reasons.  The same is probably true for an exchange, but I never tried to "hold" messages in an exchange.

Comment: one thing I have done, is all my workers get an extra (auto delete/no-ack) queue with a fanout exchange, that I use to send command messages to the workers.  For example I can send them a command `consume:queue_name` and they will.  Also this gives them a Queue by default and a way to tell them about new queues.  Basically whenever a client sumbits a job it goes into a queue specific to them, mainly to prevent them from hogging all the workers because all their messages go into one queue, just for them.  Then the workers just round robin it. etc. This way it organically prevents that.

Comment: @ArtisticPhoenix thanks a lot, I'll check.

Answer (score 3):

An exchange does not store messages, that is the job of a queue. The problem you're having is not that no *consumers* are running, but that no *queues* exist, because you have left the consumers to declare their own queues.

If you want the messages to be persistent until a consumer picks them up, you should declare:

- An exchange that the "Sender" will publish to
- A named queue attached to that exchange for each type of message that will be consumed separately (one for each routing key, if using a `direct` exchange)

These can both be declared in the Sender script, but in most cases it makes more sense to declare them once when the application is deployed, treating them like you would a database schema.

Instead of creating an anonymous queue in the Receiver script, you can then just attach to the named queue, and start receiving the messages waiting there.

The main difference this will make is how multiple consumers for the same routing key will interact:

- Multiple queues attached to a single exchange, as in your existing code, create *multiple copies* of each message. This is useful if you have different consumers doing different things with the same messages.
- Multiple consumers attached to a single queue, as I've suggested above, will *share out* the messages, with each being processed by a different consumer essentially at random. This is useful it you have multiple identical consumers to deal with a large number of messages.

You might find [this RabbitMQ simulator](http://tryrabbitmq.com/) useful to visualise the difference.

You might find you actually want a mixture:

- Pre-declare a queue for each consumer which *must see every message*, to ensure a copy of each message is stored until *that particular consumer* is ready to read it.
- Declare additional temporary queues in additional consumers to pick up *an extra copy* of messages as they come in.

As a final note, there are two mechanisms in RabbitMQ for falling back to *different* processing for messages that can't be processed:

- An [Alternate Exchange](https://www.rabbitmq.com/ae.html) captures messages that would be discarded from an exchange (because there is no appropriate queue bound).
- A [Dead Letter Exchange](https://www.rabbitmq.com/dlx.html) captures messages that would be discarded from a *queue* (e.g. because it was rejected by a consumer, or reached a configured timeout).

An AE might be useful in your example if you don't actually want to process the missed messages normally, you just want to detect them, e.g. listing them in an error log.